# using a slide toggle in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am currently using a checkbox and i would like to switch and use the the slide toggle but i am having some trouble configuring it and making it work the same way like the checkbox.

This is how i have my checkbox:

```
<input class="form-control" [attr.disabled]="item.statusId == 1 ? true : null"
       type="checkbox" [checked]="item.status" (click)="updateItem($event, item)" />
```

This is the toggle switch i am trying to use:

```
<div class="checkbox toggle-switch">
  <label>
      <input [attr.disabled]="item.statusId == 1 ? true : null"
       type="checkbox" [checked]="item.status" (click)="updateItem($event, item)" >
  </label>
</div>
```

When i run the code i could see the toggle switch fine but when i click on it to toggle either on or off - my click function doesn't get fired and binding on [checked] to see whether to show the toggle either on or off is not working. Not sure what i am missing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a more your requirement? You want to use slide toggle instead of checkbox? You want to control the Button On/Off using the checkbox?

Comment: @Rak2018 I have updated my post - hopefully it is a bit more clear.